# Como mejorar consulta compleja de "movimientos de socios" de mariadb

Tags: sql, mariadb

La siguiente consulta es algo compleja y surge a partir de movimientos de una tabla "socios", con un Trigger realizo los registros de modificaciones de dicha tabla y esta registra todo con detalles, lo modificado, por cuál usuario y en que computadora. Y es bastante lenta la consulta para presentar al usuario. Presento a continuación las tablas que pertenecen a la consulta

**Tabla socios**

```
CREATE TABLE `socios` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `nombre` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COLLATE 'utf8mb3_general_ci',
    `apellido` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COLLATE 'utf8mb3_general_ci',
    `direccionparticular` VARCHAR(200) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb3_general_ci',
    `direccionoficina` VARCHAR(200) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb3_general_ci',
    `localidad` VARCHAR(200) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb3_general_ci',
    `telefonoparticular` VARCHAR(200) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb3_general_ci',
    `telefonocelular` VARCHAR(200) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb3_general_ci',
    `telefonolaboral` VARCHAR(200) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb3_general_ci',
    `email` VARCHAR(200) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb3_general_ci',
    `horariosdecobro` VARCHAR(200) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb3_general_ci',
    `monto` DECIMAL(12,2) NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    `serie` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `telemarketer` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `estado` INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `observaciones` MEDIUMTEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb3_general_ci',
    `fechadeinscripcion` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
    `fechaultimamodificacion` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
    `periododecuotanormal` INT(5) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `numerodesocio` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
    UNIQUE INDEX `serie` (`serie`, `numerodesocio`) USING BTREE,
    UNIQUE INDEX `nombre` (`nombre`, `apellido`, `direccionparticular`, `telefonoparticular`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `FK_socios_telemarketer` (`telemarketer`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `FK_socios_cupon_color` (`serie`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `FK_socios_socio_estado` (`estado`) USING BTREE,
    CONSTRAINT `FK_socios_empleados` FOREIGN KEY (`telemarketer`) REFERENCES `nueva`.`empleados` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `FK_socios_seriedesocios` FOREIGN KEY (`serie`) REFERENCES `nueva`.`seriedesocios` (`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT `FK_socios_socio_estado` FOREIGN KEY (`estado`) REFERENCES `nueva`.`socio_estado` (`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
COLLATE='utf8mb3_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=0;
```

**Tabla socio_estado**

```
CREATE TABLE `socio_estado` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `estado` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb3_general_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
    UNIQUE INDEX `estado` (`estado`) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='utf8mb3_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=2
;
```

*Contenido de la tabla*

```
INSERT INTO `socio_estado` (`id`, `estado`) VALUES (0, 'Alta');
INSERT INTO `socio_estado` (`id`, `estado`) VALUES (1, 'Baja');
INSERT INTO `socio_estado` (`id`, `estado`) VALUES (2, 'Suspendido');
```

**Tabla empleados**
Esta tabla se refiere a los empleados, "responsables" que modifican las tablas, y los telemarketers de los socios.

```
CREATE TABLE `empleados` (
    `apellido` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb3_general_ci',
    `contrasena` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COLLATE 'utf8mb3_general_ci',
    `correoelectronico` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb3_general_ci',
    `domicilio` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb3_general_ci',
    `facebook` VARCHAR(200) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb3_general_ci',
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `nombre` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb3_general_ci',
    `telefono` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb3_general_ci',
    `sueldo` DECIMAL(12,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `periododecobroendias` INT(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `roldeempleado` INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `habilitado` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `eliminado` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `comision` DECIMAL(12,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '20.00',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
    UNIQUE INDEX `nombre` (`nombre`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `habilitado` (`habilitado`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `roldeempleado` (`roldeempleado`) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='utf8mb3_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=1
;
```

**Tabla terminales**
Esta tabla se refiere a las computadoras que estan como clientes del sistema, y es de donde se realizan los cambios en las tablas.

```
CREATE TABLE `terminales` (
    `cajaindependiente` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `computerid` VARCHAR(600) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COLLATE 'utf8mb3_general_ci',
    `conexionactual` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb3_general_ci',
    `empleadoactual` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `estado` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `grupo` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb3_general_ci',
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `imprimirticket` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `iniciaconwindows` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `mysqldump` VARCHAR(600) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb3_general_ci',
    `nombredeimpresora` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COLLATE 'utf8mb3_general_ci',
    `nombrepc` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COLLATE 'utf8mb3_general_ci',
    `pantallacompleta` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `copiadeseguridad` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `ultimobackup` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `usuariopredefinido` INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
    UNIQUE INDEX `nombrepc` (`nombrepc`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `FK_terminales_terminales_estado` (`estado`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `id` (`id`) USING BTREE,
    CONSTRAINT `FK_terminales_terminales_estado` FOREIGN KEY (`estado`) REFERENCES `nueva`.`terminales_estado` (`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
COLLATE='utf8mb3_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

**Tabla Movimiento_socios**
Donde se guardan todas las modificaciones a los cambios de la tabla "socios"

```
CREATE TABLE `movimientos_socios` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `socio` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `empleado` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `tipodemovimiento` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `cuotaactual` DECIMAL(11,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `estado` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `datoanterior` DECIMAL(11,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `datonuevo` DECIMAL(11,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `datoanteriortxt` VARCHAR(200) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb3_general_ci',
    `datonuevotxt` VARCHAR(200) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb3_general_ci',
    `host` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `fecha` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `FK_movimientos_socios_empleados` (`empleado`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `FK_movimientos_socios_movimientos_socios_tipodemovimiento` (`tipodemovimiento`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `FK_movimientos_socios_socios` (`socio`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `FK_movimientos_socios_terminales` (`host`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `fecha` (`fecha`) USING BTREE,
    CONSTRAINT `FK_movimientos_socios_empleados` FOREIGN KEY (`empleado`) REFERENCES `sgc`.`empleados` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `FK_movimientos_socios_movimientos_socios_tipodemovimiento` FOREIGN KEY (`tipodemovimiento`) REFERENCES `sgc`.`movimientos_socios_tipodemovimiento` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `FK_movimientos_socios_socios` FOREIGN KEY (`socio`) REFERENCES `sgc`.`socios` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `FK_movimientos_socios_terminales` FOREIGN KEY (`host`) REFERENCES `sgc`.`terminales` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
COLLATE='utf8mb3_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

**Tabla movimientos_socios_tipo**

```
CREATE TABLE `movimientos_socios_tipodemovimiento` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `nombre` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb3_general_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
    UNIQUE INDEX `nombre` (`nombre`) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='utf8mb3_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=20
;
```

y datos de la tabla:

```
INSERT INTO `movimientos_socios_tipodemovimiento` (`id`, `nombre`) VALUES (1, 'MODIFICACIÓN DE NOMBRE');
INSERT INTO `movimientos_socios_tipodemovimiento` (`id`, `nombre`) VALUES (2, 'MODIFICACIÓN DE APELLIDO');
INSERT INTO `movimientos_socios_tipodemovimiento` (`id`, `nombre`) VALUES (3, 'MODIFICACIÓN DE DIRECCIÓN PARTICULAR');
INSERT INTO `movimientos_socios_tipodemovimiento` (`id`, `nombre`) VALUES (4, 'MODIFICACIÓN DE DIRECCIÓN OFICINA');
INSERT INTO `movimientos_socios_tipodemovimiento` (`id`, `nombre`) VALUES (5, 'MODIFICACIÓN DE LOCALIDAD');
INSERT INTO `movimientos_socios_tipodemovimiento` (`id`, `nombre`) VALUES (6, 'MODIFICACIÓN DE TELEFONO PARTICULAR');
INSERT INTO `movimientos_socios_tipodemovimiento` (`id`, `nombre`) VALUES (7, 'MODIFICACIÓN DE TELEFONO CELULAR');
INSERT INTO `movimientos_socios_tipodemovimiento` (`id`, `nombre`) VALUES (8, 'MODIFICACIÓN DE TELEFONO LABORAL');
INSERT INTO `movimientos_socios_tipodemovimiento` (`id`, `nombre`) VALUES (9, 'MODIFICACIÓN DE E-MAIL');
INSERT INTO `movimientos_socios_tipodemovimiento` (`id`, `nombre`) VALUES (10, 'MODIFICACIÓN DE HORARIOS DE COBRO');
INSERT INTO `movimientos_socios_tipodemovimiento` (`id`, `nombre`) VALUES (11, 'MODIFICACIÓN DE MONTO DE PAGO O CUOTA');
INSERT INTO `movimientos_socios_tipodemovimiento` (`id`, `nombre`) VALUES (12, 'MODIFICACIÓN DE CUPÓN');
INSERT INTO `movimientos_socios_tipodemovimiento` (`id`, `nombre`) VALUES (13, 'CAMBIO DE TELEMARKETER');
INSERT INTO `movimientos_socios_tipodemovimiento` (`id`, `nombre`) VALUES (14, 'SUSPENCIÓN DEL SOCIO');
INSERT INTO `movimientos_socios_tipodemovimiento` (`id`, `nombre`) VALUES (15, 'REACTIVACIÓN DEL SOCIO');
INSERT INTO `movimientos_socios_tipodemovimiento` (`id`, `nombre`) VALUES (16, 'ANOTACIONES EN OBSERVACIONES CAMBIADAS');
INSERT INTO `movimientos_socios_tipodemovimiento` (`id`, `nombre`) VALUES (17, 'ALTA NUEVO SOCIO');
INSERT INTO `movimientos_socios_tipodemovimiento` (`id`, `nombre`) VALUES (18, 'BAJA AL SOCIO');
INSERT INTO `movimientos_socios_tipodemovimiento` (`id`, `nombre`) VALUES (19, 'MODIFICACIÓN DE NÚMERO DE SOCIO');
```

**Trigger de movimientos_socios**
De inserción de un nuevo registro:

```
CREATE DEFINER=``@`` TRIGGER `movimientos_socio_alta` AFTER INSERT ON `socios` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT INTO movimientos_socios (tipodemovimiento, socio, empleado, host, cuotaactual, estado, datoanteriortxt, datonuevotxt, fecha, datoanterior) VALUES (17, NEW.id, obtenerempleado(),  OBTENERTERMINALID(), IFNULL(NEW.monto,0),NEW.estado, NEW.nombre, NEW.apellido, NOW(), new.telemarketer);
END
```

Y modificacion:

```
CREATE DEFINER=``@`` TRIGGER `movimientos_socio_movimiento` AFTER UPDATE ON `socios` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF (not NEW.nombre <=> OLD.nombre ) THEN
INSERT INTO movimientos_socios (tipodemovimiento, socio, empleado, cuotaactual, host, estado, datoanteriortxt, datonuevotxt) VALUES (1, NEW.id, obtenerempleado(), NEW.monto, OBTENERTERMINALID(), NEW.estado, OLD.nombre, NEW.nombre);
end if;
IF (not NEW.apellido <=> OLD.apellido) THEN
INSERT INTO movimientos_socios (tipodemovimiento, socio, empleado, cuotaactual, host, estado, datoanteriortxt, datonuevotxt) VALUES (2, NEW.id, obtenerempleado(), NEW.monto, OBTENERTERMINALID(), NEW.estado, OLD.apellido, NEW.apellido);
end if;
IF (not NEW.direccionparticular <=> OLD.direccionparticular) THEN
INSERT INTO movimientos_socios (tipodemovimiento, socio, empleado, cuotaactual, host, estado, datoanteriortxt, datonuevotxt) VALUES (3, NEW.id, obtenerempleado(), NEW.monto, OBTENERTERMINALID(), NEW.estado, OLD.direccionparticular, NEW.direccionparticular);
end if;
IF (not NEW.direccionoficina <=> OLD.direccionoficina ) THEN
INSERT INTO movimientos_socios (tipodemovimiento, socio, empleado, cuotaactual, host, estado, datoanteriortxt, datonuevotxt) VALUES (4, NEW.id, obtenerempleado(), NEW.monto, OBTENERTERMINALID(), NEW.estado, OLD.direccionoficina, NEW.direccionoficina);
end if;
IF (not NEW.localidad <=>  OLD.localidad ) THEN
INSERT INTO movimientos_socios (tipodemovimiento, socio, empleado, cuotaactual, host, estado, datoanteriortxt, datonuevotxt) VALUES (5, NEW.id, obtenerempleado(), NEW.monto, OBTENERTERMINALID(), NEW.estado, OLD.localidad, NEW.localidad);
end if;
IF (not NEW.telefonoparticular <=> OLD.telefonoparticular ) THEN
INSERT INTO movimientos_socios (tipodemovimiento, socio, empleado, cuotaactual, host, estado, datoanteriortxt, datonuevotxt) VALUES (6, NEW.id, obtenerempleado(), NEW.monto, OBTENERTERMINALID(), NEW.estado, OLD.telefonoparticular, NEW.telefonoparticular);
end if;
IF (not NEW.telefonocelular <=> OLD.telefonocelular ) THEN
INSERT INTO movimientos_socios (tipodemovimiento, socio, empleado, cuotaactual, host, estado, datoanteriortxt, datonuevotxt) VALUES (7, NEW.id, obtenerempleado(), NEW.monto, OBTENERTERMINALID(), NEW.estado, OLD.telefonocelular, NEW.telefonocelular);
end if;
IF (not NEW.telefonolaboral <=> OLD.telefonolaboral ) THEN
INSERT INTO movimientos_socios (tipodemovimiento, socio, empleado, cuotaactual, host, estado, datoanteriortxt, datonuevotxt) VALUES (8, NEW.id, obtenerempleado(), NEW.monto, OBTENERTERMINALID(), NEW.estado, OLD.telefonolaboral, NEW.telefonolaboral);
end if;
IF (not NEW.email <=> OLD.email) THEN
INSERT INTO movimientos_socios (tipodemovimiento, socio, empleado, cuotaactual, host, estado, datoanteriortxt, datonuevotxt) VALUES (9, NEW.id, obtenerempleado(), NEW.monto, OBTENERTERMINALID(), NEW.estado, OLD.email, NEW.email);
end if;
IF (not NEW.horariosdecobro <=> OLD.horariosdecobro) THEN
INSERT INTO movimientos_socios (tipodemovimiento, socio, empleado, cuotaactual, host, estado, datoanteriortxt, datonuevotxt) VALUES (10, NEW.id, obtenerempleado(), NEW.monto, OBTENERTERMINALID(), NEW.estado, OLD.horariosdecobro, NEW.horariosdecobro);
end if;
IF (not NEW.monto <=> OLD.monto) THEN
INSERT INTO movimientos_socios (tipodemovimiento, socio, empleado, cuotaactual, host, estado, datoanterior, datonuevo) VALUES (11, NEW.id, obtenerempleado(), NEW.monto, OBTENERTERMINALID(), NEW.estado, OLD.monto, NEW.monto);
end if;
IF (not NEW.serie <=> OLD.serie ) THEN
INSERT INTO movimientos_socios (tipodemovimiento, socio, empleado, cuotaactual, host, estado,datoanterior, datonuevo) VALUES (12, NEW.id, obtenerempleado(), NEW.monto, OBTENERTERMINALID(), NEW.estado, OLD.serie, NEW.serie);
end if;
IF (not NEW.telemarketer <=> OLD.telemarketer ) THEN
INSERT INTO movimientos_socios (tipodemovimiento, socio, empleado, cuotaactual, host, estado, datoanterior, datonuevo) VALUES (13, NEW.id, obtenerempleado(), NEW.monto, OBTENERTERMINALID(), NEW.estado, OLD.telemarketer, NEW.telemarketer);
end if;
IF (not NEW.estado <=> OLD.estado ) AND (NEW.estado=3 ) then
INSERT INTO movimientos_socios (tipodemovimiento, socio, empleado, cuotaactual, host, estado, datoanteriortxt, datonuevotxt) VALUES (14, NEW.id, obtenerempleado(), NEW.monto, OBTENERTERMINALID(), NEW.estado, (CASE when OLD.estado=1 then 'Alta' ELSE 'Baja' END ), 'Suspendido');
end if;
IF (not NEW.estado <=> OLD.estado ) AND NEW.estado=1 then
INSERT INTO movimientos_socios (tipodemovimiento, socio, empleado, cuotaactual, host, estado, datoanteriortxt, datonuevotxt) VALUES (15, NEW.id, obtenerempleado(), NEW.monto, OBTENERTERMINALID(), NEW.estado, (CASE when OLD.estado=3 then 'Suspendido' ELSE 'Baja' END ), 'Alta');
end if;
IF (not NEW.observaciones <=> OLD.observaciones) then
INSERT INTO movimientos_socios (tipodemovimiento, socio, empleado, cuotaactual, host, estado, datoanteriortxt, datonuevotxt) VALUES (16, NEW.id, obtenerempleado(), NEW.monto, OBTENERTERMINALID(), NEW.estado, OLD.observaciones, NEW.observaciones);
end if;
IF (not NEW.estado <=> OLD.estado ) AND (NEW.estado=2 ) then
INSERT INTO movimientos_socios (tipodemovimiento, socio, empleado, cuotaactual, host, estado, datoanteriortxt, datonuevotxt) VALUES (18, NEW.id, obtenerempleado(), NEW.monto, OBTENERTERMINALID(), NEW.estado, (CASE when OLD.estado=1 then 'Alta'ELSE 'Suspendido' END ), 'Baja');
end if;
IF (not NEW.numerodesocio <=> OLD.numerodesocio) THEN
INSERT INTO movimientos_socios (tipodemovimiento, socio, empleado, cuotaactual, host, estado, datoanterior, datonuevo) VALUES (19, NEW.id, obtenerempleado(), NEW.monto, OBTENERTERMINALID(), NEW.estado, OLD.numerodesocio, NEW.numerodesocio);
end if;
END
```

**Consulta**
La consulta realiza una tabla en si, para poder presentar a partir de los movimientos registrados, con su "tipo de movimiento" y que sea visiblemente sencillo de comprender para el usuario

```
SELECT m.id as Id, m.fecha as "Fecha",
t.nombre AS "Tipo de Movimiento",
s.nombre as "Socio",
e.nombre AS "Respontable",
(case when t.id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 14, 15, 16, 17) THEN m.datoanteriortxt WHEN t.id IN (11, 19) then m.datoanterior WHEN t.id = 13 THEN (SELECT nombre FROM empleados WHERE id = m.datoanterior) WHEN t.id = 12 THEN (SELECT nombre FROM seriedesocios WHERE id = m.datoanterior) END) AS "Dato Anterior",
(case when t.id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 14, 15, 16, 17) THEN m.datonuevotxt WHEN t.id IN (11, 19) then m.datonuevo WHEN t.id = 13 THEN (SELECT nombre FROM empleados WHERE id = m.datonuevo) WHEN t.id = 12 THEN (SELECT nombre FROM seriedesocios WHERE id = m.datonuevo) END ) AS "Dato Nuevo",
m.cuotaactual as "Cuota Actual",
(case WHEN m.estado = 0 THEN "Alta" WHEN m.estado = 1 THEN "Baja" ELSE "Suspencion" END ) AS "Estado",
t2.nombrepc AS "Computadora"
from movimientos_socios m inner join movimientos_socios_tipodemovimiento t on m.tipodemovimiento = t.id inner join socios s on m.socio = s.id inner join empleados e on m.empleado = e.id inner join terminales t2 on m.host = t2.id order by m.id limit 40;
```

La consulta se realiza a partir de lo necesario a presentar en pantalla, limitando la consulta a 40 y ordenado por el id de movimientos_socios;
y el resultado detallado es:

```
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost [127.0.0.1]
# Thread_id: 67  Schema: nueva  QC_hit: No
# Query_time: 0.368511  Lock_time: 0.000104  Rows_sent: 40  Rows_examined: 43987
# Rows_affected: 0  Bytes_sent: 4993
```

Como se puede apreciar, rows send 40, examinados "todos" los registros
Como puedo evitar que sean examinados todos?
Existe alguna manera mas simple de generar los movimientos? cual...

Comment: ¿Manejás el concepto de _índices_?

Comment: Hay indices, claro, esta lleno de indice, no? faltan?, me haces dudar :D

Comment: Es un mar de SQL. Ahora lo vi :)

Comment: Entiendo que el número de filas examinadas se debe a los SELECT de dentro del CASE.

Comment: Entiendo lo que buscas, pero no es posible. Una consulta es una foto del estado de tus datos en un determinado instante, si quieres mostrar una parte pequeña de la foto, igual tienes que tener la foto completa. Si pudieras solo obtener la parte pequeña de la foto, el problema lo tendrías cuando traigas las otras partes pequeñas, que se generarían en otro instante y serían parte de una foto distinta.

Comment: O si existe una forma de hacerlo, te diría no lo hagas. Es más podrías pensar en particionar la lógica para tomar "fotos" de a 40 socios por ejemplo, pero es algo que deberías armar desde tu aplicación, vas disparando consultas por rangos de 40 socios despues de cada "Next" que haga el usuario, pero es innecesariamente complejo, inconsistente y peligroso.

Comment: Si tienes un tema de performance te sugeriría que veas si puedes trabajar con "planchados", "congelados", "snapshots" o como lo llames, básicamente la consulta que tienes "planchada" de forma plana  en una temporal congelada por ejemplo durante un día.

Comment: El hecho de ordenar los datos para poder definir secciones de 40 filas, hace que tenga que leer todos los datos para poder definir el orden.

Comment: ¿Como sugieres que haga la consulta de esa manera? Por un día? ¿Como un filtrado? Pongo limite 40 porque me surgió, parecía poco. Se puede realizar a estructura de otra manera? Lo loco es que si en el where coloco por fecha también recorre todos los registros